# C# get excel worksheets without office unsing OLEDB

Tags: excel, oledb

I read some of the other thread's about this topic, but it still dosn't work and I don't know why.

There is an exception: 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'-Provider not registred on local machine. I already installed Database engine for Office 2007 and 2010.

Do you have any ideas?

OS: Win 7 Prof. 64 bit

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            OleDbConnection connection = null;
            DataTable Sheets = null;

            String file = args[0];
            String filePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(args[0]);
            String connPath = "";

            if(Path.GetExtension(file).Equals(".xls"))
                connPath = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source=" + file + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0";
            else
                connPath = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + file + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\"";

            try
            {
                connection = new OleDbConnection(connPath);
                connection.Open();

            Sheets = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
```

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. You Need to complile the Project for x86 CPU. Any CPU wonnt work.

Thanks

Comment: This isn't a direct answer to your question, but as you can see, using OLEDB has a lot of limitations.  If you want full control of office files (without office), you may want to look at the openxml sdk: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396